# react-paginate Css is not getting reflected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, bootstrap-4

I am new to the `web-development` . Here, I have a pagination to do.
So, I am using the `react-paginate` library for this.

```
                     <ReactPaginate
                      previousLabel={'<'}
                      nextLabel={'>'}
                      initialPage={this.props.activePage}
                      pageCount={this.props.totalPages}
                      marginPagesDisplayed={0}
                      pageRangeDisplayed={2}
                      onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
                      containerClassName={'pagination'}
                      subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
                      activeClassName={'active'}
                    />
```

So, When I used this, 
 I am getting the 
[image]

Here activePage is the current page, and I want to show only two numbers on that page for the pagination first time. So, Is there any thing that I am missing, Thanks for help.